# jQuery: How Do I Make textarea Stay In The Same Position After I Press Enter?

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, alert

We got the first part down in the question but, I want my code to stay on the same line as before if I don't type in a long enough message.

Here is what I am talking about:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var para = $('#UserInput');
  $('textarea').keyup(function(e){
    var length = this.value.length; 
    var newval =  this.value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && length > 6 ){ 
        para.append(newval);
            this.value = "";
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && length < 6){ 
        alert("Not long enough!"); 
    }
    });
});
```

If I type in `He`, for example, but, I meant to type in `Hello` Here is the Results:

```
He \\"Alert Message"
llo \\"Prints 'He' on the first line and 'llo' on the second line, if I don't backspace."
```

Intended results:

```
He \\"Alert Message"
Hello \\(ON THE SAME LINE) "Prints 'Hello' on the first line"
```

Comment: the problem in `('textarea').length` you must use it like this `$(this).length` OR like this `$('textarea').length`

Comment: @ChadidiAbdellah I tried that and it didn't work but, I don't think I did it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `var length = this.value` for `$("textarea").length` to store `.length` of `textarea` `value`; correct syntax errors at `if` condition; swap `>` for `<` at first `if`, `<` for `>` at second `if` condition

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var para = $('#UserInput');
  $('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    var length = val.length; 
    var newval =  val.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "");
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && length < 5) { 
        para.append(newval);
            this.value = "";
    }
    if (length < 5) { 
        alert("Not long enough!"); 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p id="UserInput"></p>
<hr id="LineOne">
<textarea maxlength="100"; minlength="5"; placeholder="Type Message Here:">
</textarea>
```

Comment: I put if (e.keyCode == 13 && length < 6) so the alert wouldn't pop up every time you typed in a character. I have a question, How do I put it so that instead of it entering in the textarea it stays in the exact same spot? For example: `He` "Alert" `He (Same Line) llo` instead of  `He` "Alert" `He (New Line) llo`

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist _"How do I put it so that instead of it entering in the textarea it stays in the exact same spot? "_ Should input be displayed in `textarea` if `value` is equal to or greater than `5`? What do you mean by "New Line"?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is instead of it entering to a new line if the message is less than 6 it stays were it's at.

Comment: _"What I'm trying to say is instead of it entering to a new line if the message is less than 6 it stays were it's at"_ Substitute `""` for `<br>` as replacement string at `.replace()`; see updated post.

Comment: I fixed the question. Take a look.